# Rewriting observable sequence to make more sense

Tags: rxjs, observable, typeahead, bootstrap-typeahead, angular2-observables

I'm creating a typeahead that remotely calls an api every time someone types in the input, with a small delay after typing.

This code is from [bootstrap 4 typeahead example docs (Wikipedia example)](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples). It makes no sense to me with all the `.call` and `_do` functions.

Angular Component

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operator/map';
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operator/debounceTime';
import { distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import { _catch } from 'rxjs/operator/catch';
import { _do } from 'rxjs/operator/do';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operator/switchMap';

search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
  _do.call(
     switchMap.call(
        _do.call(distinctUntilChanged.call(
           debounceTime.call(text$, 300)),
           () => this.searching = true),
           (term) => _catch.call(
              _do.call(this._service.search(term),
              () => this.searchFailed = false),
              () => {
              this.searchFailed = true;
              return of.call([]);
        })),
     () => this.searching = false);
```

HTML

```
      <md-input-container>
        <input mdInput [ngbTypeahead]="search"
           [(ngModel)]="model"
           [formControl]="lookupSubscriberControl"
           type="text"
           placeholder="Search by Name">
        <button type="submit" mdSuffix class="material-icons">search</button>
     </md-input-container>
```

1) What does this do in English? Right now I do not understand how to read this in normal terms and therefore cannot rewrite it for my needs.

2) Can someone help me rewrite this in a more readable format? Such as using the chained sequence of promises, or anything else that makes more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that does seem somewhat tortured. I assume it was done since they are importing the `operators` directly rather than using the `add/` variants to add the operators the the Observable prototype.

Basically if we were to rewrite this as we traditionally see `Observables` it would look like this:

```
search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
  text$.debounceTime(300)
   .distinctUntilChanged()
   .do(() => this.searching = true)
   .switchMap(term => 
     this._service.search(term)
       .do(() => this.searchFailed = false)
       .catch(() => {
         this.searchFailed = true;
         return Observable.of([]);
       })
   )
   .do(() => this.searching = false);
```

Note you will also need to change the imports for the operators too, so that they get added to the Observable prototype:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
```

Fundamentally all it is doing is receiving an Observable of search queries which it is debouncing, so that requests aren't made with stale data, then it is removing duplicate consecutive queries. Then it uses the `do` blocks to apply some side-effects that will presumably be reflected in the UI. And finally it is making a request for each query which processes the search request and returns an array of results. If some thing goes wrong it catches the failure and sets and error state before returning an empty array of data.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for.